# Is the new Firebase messaging server key restricted to messaging?

Tags: firebase, server, push-notification, key, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is the new server key restricted to messaging only?

**explanation:**
In firebase project settings, I can get "old" and new server keys(cloud messaging tab). 
The old ones don't work to send push notifications via https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send because the response says that it is a legacy server key. But it can be restricted to certain google apis here https://console.developers.google.com/apis.
The new is not listed in google apis console, but works.

We want to share the server key with partners, but won't allow to do other stuff. The new HTTP API V1 with OAuth2 is not an option unfortunately.

According to docs:

> Server key (for legacy protocols): A server key that authorizes your app server for access to Google services, including sending messages via the Firebase Cloud Messaging legacy protocols.

Which services are here meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got response from Google: Yes, the new server key is restricted to cloud messaging only.